# Generating/Populating Explain tables in DB2 and usage of db2exfmt

Tags: database, db2, sql-execution-plan

I'm having a problem while i'm trying to collect explain plan with the `db2exfmt` tool.

Can some body explain me the process of how to use that tool?

My requirement is to collect cost of a stored procedure. I have the `EXPLAIN` tables created in instance 'XYZ' schema and I have a procedure named "UNNAMED", which has the package name "P123456" and the schema "ABCD".

I used the following commands:

```
! db2exfmt -d SAMPLE -e DB2INST1 -s ABCD -n P123456 -g TIC -w -1 -#***5*** -t
```

Wherein 5 is the Section Number of the part of the procedure I'm trying to collect cost for.

Furthermore, I have also tried to do the following:

1)  **Identify the package corresponding to the stored proc :**

```
select r.routineschema, r.routinename, rd.bname as packagename 
from syscat.routines r, syscat.routinedep rd 
where 
    r.specificname=rd.specificname and
    r.routineschema=rd.routineschema and 
    rd.btype='K' and 
    r.routineschema = 'XYZ' and 
    r.routinename = 'ABCD'
```

2)  **Identify the section number for the SQL statement :**

```
select sectno, text 
from syscat.statements 
where pkgschema='XYZ' and pkgname='P123456'
```

3)  **Populate Explain tables :**

```
call EXPLAIN_FROM_CATALOG( 'XYZ', 'P123456', ' ', 5, 'SYSTOOLS', ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
```

The latter throws an error:

> Message: The parameter mode OUT or INOUT is not valid for a parameter in the routine named "EXPLAIN_FROM_CATALOG" with specific name "EXPLAIN_FROM_CATALOG" (parameter number "5", name "EXPLAIN_SCHEMA").. SQLCODE=-469, SQLSTATE=42886, DRIVER=3.50.152

I am logged in as USER : "MNO" and want the explain tables under SYSTOOLS schema to be populated.

Can someone please help me resolve the problem?

Comment: Are you running it from the command line or via a tool like Data Studio?

Comment: Hi , I'm running it from Aqua Data Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message indicates, and [the manual says](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056252.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0&lang=en),  `explain_schema` is an `INOUT` parameter, so you cannot specify a literal value.

You may want to try wrapping the procedure call in a compound statement, providing declared variables for each OUT and INOUT parameter, something like:

```
begin
  declare v_schema varchar(50) default 'SYSTOOLS';
  declare v_req, v_srcname, v_srcschema, v_srcver varchar(128);
  declare v_ts timestamp;

  call EXPLAIN_FROM_CATALOG( 'XYZ', 'P123456', ' ', 5, v_schema,
                             v_req, v_ts, v_srcname, v_srcschema, v_srcver );
end
```

PS. Code is not tested

Comment: HI, i still get the following error :   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.50.152
 Message: The number of variables in the EXECUTE statement, the number of variables in the OPEN statement, or the number of arguments in an OPEN statement for a parameterized cursor is not equal to the number of values required.. SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, DRIVER=3.50.152

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify every IN/OUT parameter with a "?" - running it will then prompt you for the input value ('SYSTOOLS').
So try

```
call EXPLAIN_FROM_CATALOG( 'XYZ', 'P123456', ' ', 5, **?**, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
```